# HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Exception

Tags: java, servlets

Before you say "DUPLICATE", I assure you I have looked at the others. They are all different from what I am asking. So I had the web app working, changed gears and came back to it and now I get this.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet com.xxxx.xxx.xxx.AppConfig threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:309)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
```

I looked at a few of the other similar issues people were having and there was always something like `RequestedMaping(blah)` but thats where things are different. I am working on a restful sevice, and all I have in my project is `Path(blah)`. I assume they are similar, but thats it. One of the solutions to the other issues was to pu `*.do` or something like that in the requested mapping, but even when I had mine working I never had that in the project.

The only difference I can think that I made to the project was adding a third class to the AppConfig `getClasses()` here:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class AppConfig extends Application {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppConfig.class);

    /**
     * @see Application#getClasses()
     */
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        s.add(EntityManagementResource.class);
        s.add(AccumuloInterfaceResource.class);
        s.add(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
        return s;
    }
```

before I didn't have the `AccumuloInterfaceResource.class` there, now I do?

Thanks for anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;`

Looks to me like you have two JAX-RS libraries loaded. The first time you ran, it used the one you expected. Now you're coming back and it's finding the other one first.

You need to take a look at your classpath and see what is contributing JAX-RS libraries. I'll bet you have at least two.

The getProperties() method was added in Java EE 7. So you might still have artifacts that are Java EE 6 compliant.

Comment: Yep turns out a colleague updated the pom doing something like you described. Thanks!